# What does Axes and Keys in NGUI do?

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, ngui

In NGUI of Unity 3D,
there is a script called UI Camera (Script).
At the Bottom of the Inspector, there are parameters for Axes and Keys.
How do you use them, and what are they good for?

Answer (score 0):

From the NGUI documentation for UICamera:

> Axes and Keys section lets you choose which axes result in which movement.

http://www.tasharen.com/forum/index.php?topic=6711.0

The axes and keys are controller inputs. You can find the settings for the parameters you see (vertical, horizontal, etc) under Edit> Project Settings> Input.

An example could be using the arrow keys to scroll through buttons and hit the return key to select instead of using your mouse and mouse click. To try that out, take a look at the example scene: "Example 4 - Controller Input".

- Attach the UIKeyNavigation component to the play, options, and exit button.
- In inspector for UIKeyNavigation on the "play" button, check "starts selected".
- In the inspector for UICamera, uncheck mouse and touch so we can see the keyboard input.
- Now hit play and press the up or down arrow keys which will now scroll through the buttons.

Comment: Yeah I read that one, but I still dont get it.
I think its because Im a beginner in programming and unity, might you explain it more deeper?

Comment: Sure! I updated my answer, does that help? @SoloplayerNP